# Java Neuroph framework and GPS data clusterization

Tags: java, coordinates, neural-network, cluster-analysis

I have a set of GPS coordinates and have to clusterize them. For this task i have to use neural network and Java language. I am totally new in neural networks, so i found i framework called Neuroph. As i understand after my research, i have to use Multi Layer Perceptron (MLP) ir Radial Basis Function (RBF) neural network to complete my task.
Determining how many clusters i have is not a problem. Problem is, how to make neural network to show in which cluster place has to be?

Sample data:
CLUSTER1
54.930225, 23.867619
54.930204, 23.867532
54.930258, 23.86754

CLUSTER2
54.920432, 23.901341
54.920323, 23.901263
54.920187, 23.901156
54.92022, 23.9013

CLUSTER3
54.900466, 23.856597
54.900499, 23.85644
54.900452, 23.85651

I use this data for neural network to learn. My setup is like this:
Multi layer Perceptron, 2 input neurons, 2 hidden neurons, 1 output neuron.
OR
Radial Basis Function, 2 input neurons, 2 hidden neurons, 1 output neuron.
This is my training set:

> +-----------+-----------+---+
>     | 54.930225 | 23.867619 | 1 |
>     | 54.930204 | 23.867532 | 1 |
>     | 54.930258 | 23.86754  | 1 |
>     | 54.920432 | 23.901341 | 2 |
>     | 54.920323 | 23.901263 | 2 |
>     | 54.920187 | 23.901156 | 2 |
>     | 54.92022  | 23.9013   | 2 |
>     | 54.900466 | 23.856597 | 3 |
>     | 54.900499 | 23.85644  | 3 |
>     | 54.900452 | 23.85651  | 3 |
>   +-----------+-----------+---+

While training, i select max error = 0,01 and learning rate = 0,2. With these parameters Multilayer Perceptron does not stop learning for a very long time, so i change parameters to 0,2 and 0,5.
When learning is finished, i expect to set parameters (coordinates) and get number of cluster which these coordinates belong to. In Multilayer perceptron i always get 0,99... and ir RBF i get 0,9 or 1,9. As parameters i use last coordinates from CLUSTER3.
Am i missing something or i still don't get the point how neural network should work? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could translate number of classes into easier form for neural network to predict. Instead of numbers 1-3 do three columns which will represent questions like below:

column1: the X coord

column2: the Y coord

column3:"is this element from class nr 1?" and answer 0 (No) 1 (Yes)

column4:"is this element from class nr 2?" and answer 0 (No) 1 (Yes)

column5:"is this element from class nr 3?" and answer 0 (No) 1 (Yes)

```
+-----------+-----------+---+---+---+
| 54.930225 | 23.867619 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 54.920432 | 23.901341 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
...
```

Doing so u have to change number of output neurons to 3 of course. 
I think this will do what you want to accomplish.

If I get second part of your question right. If u get answers like 0.99 You should just round them up.

Comment: Ok, i prepared a training set like this and tested it. Now i have another problem. How to determine how many neurons i need in hidden layer? I tried with the same amount as input neurons, and with both, sigmoidal and tanh transfer functions. Problem now is, that it doesn't matter what coordinates i set, it always is in second cluster (RBF) or third (MLP).